# AWK count occurrences of column A based on uniqueness of column B

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with several columns and I want to count the occurrence of one column based on a second columns value being unique to the first column

For example:

```
column 10            column 15
-------------------------------
orange               New York
green                New York
blue                 New York
gold                 New York
orange               Amsterdam
blue                 New York
green                New York
orange               Sweden
blue                 Tokyo
gold                 New York
```

I am fairly new to using commands like awk and am looking to gain more practical knowledge.

I've tried some different variations of

```
awk '{A[$10 OFS $15]++} END {for (k in A) print k, A[k]}' myfile
```

but, not quite understanding the code, the output was not what I've expected.

I am expecting output of

```
orange     3
blue       2
green      1
gold       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk. I assume tab is your field separator.

```
awk '{count[$10 FS $15]++}END{for(j in count) print j}' FS='\t' file | cut -d $'\t' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Output:

```
      3 orange
      2 blue
      1 green
      1 gold
```

I suppose it could be more elegant.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I seem to only be getting an output of just 1. I may have my fields wrong.

Comment: made some adjustments. I removed the FS = \t and the cut command. and am much closer to what i am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Single GNU `awk` invocation version (Works with non-GNU awk too, just doesn't sort the output):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="\t" }
        NR>1 { names[$2,$1]=$1 }
        END { for (n in names) colors[names[n]]++;
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc";
              for (c in colors) print c, colors[c] }' input.tsv
orange  3
blue    2
gold    1
green   1
```

Adjust column numbers as needed to match real data.

---

Bonus solution that uses sqlite3:

```
$ sqlite3 -batch -noheader <<EOF
.mode tabs
.import input.tsv names
SELECT "column 10", count(DISTINCT "column 15") AS total
FROM names
GROUP BY "column 10"
ORDER BY total DESC, "column 10";
EOF
orange  3
blue    2
gold    1
green   1
```